# RDS Remote App Hangs for only certain users

Tags: rds, remoteapp

I've got remote app working for all users just fine.  We all connect through a single gateway that allows access to all app servers.  This worked well for months.

Recently 2 users can no longer use remote app.  Every app (on any server) shows the login process, but where the app should appear, this is shown instead (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp72H.png) (then times out 5 minutes later).  This happens no matter the app, or the server the app is hosted on.

They can log into the servers via rdp normally (and through the gateway too), this is only when using remote app...

The only correlation is that these users are testing out webDAV in our environment...  This is the only thing they have in common.  The event logs of the clients, gateway, and app servers are all clean.

Comment: `The only correlation is that these users are testing out webDAV in our environment` - Can you provide some detail on this?

Comment: We setup a new server that hosts IIS and the webDav feature.  after the users mapped drives to this host using webDav, they could no longer open remote-app's.  I can't help but think it's a red-herring, but it's too coincidental to not at least mention.

Comment: It almost seems like a logon script hanging due to a permissions problem on the mapped drive. When these users log into an RDP session do they get the WebDAV mapped drive?

Comment: yes, it maps just fine.  I included that screen shot because that is exactly what is shown to the two users regardless of app or server being used.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually due to a windows update...  I removed everything from the last round of updates, and RDS is working again.  It only seems to be affecting Windows 8.1 users on IE11 for now.  I'll update when I narrow down to what update caused the issue.